# Swift: How can I successively change my variable in a if-else statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm all new to Swift since three days back and are currently trying to make a simple if-else statement, just to try it's functions, in which I want to change the value of the string that's supposed to be returned from my function like this:

```
class TestClass(){    
var TestString = "0"
    
    func TestFunc()->String {
        
        
        if (TestString == "0") {
            TestString = "5"
        }
        else if (TestString == "5") {
            TestString = "8"
        }
        else if (TestString == "8") {
            TestString = "12"
        }
        else if (TestString == "12") {
            TestString = "17"
        }
        else if (TestString == "17") {
            TestString = "25"
        }
       
        return TestString
    }
}
```

But when I test the method with this code from the InterfaceController:

```
@IBAction func test(){
        
        print(TestClass().TestFunc())
        
    }
```

The first time I tap the button it prints "5" as expected. But the second and third, and so on, time it keeps printing "5" even though I constantly updates the value of the TestString after each if/else if statement. It feels like the TestString doesn't update it's value or if it resets between every tap.

Does anyone sit on a great solution to this?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `TestClass` each time with `TestClass()` that intializes `TestString = "0"`.

Comment: Just a comment, but if you use digits in strings like that, people might wonder if perhaps you should be using numbers instead. It might be better to use, for example, "A", "B", "C" instead of "0", "5", "8".

Answer (score 2):

Like @sash-sinha commented, the problem you're seeing is that '''print(TestClass().TestFunc())''' creates a new object of type TestClass every time it is called and the state you're expecting to keep around is actually reset every time.

Create a `var test = TestClass()` object somewhere and then use it with `print(test.TestFunc())`

A couple of things:

1. Although your cascading `if / else if / else if` works, if you are going to treat all cases of an input using `switch` can be clearer (and it's easier not to miss cases)
2. Usually in Swift variable names and function names start with a lowercase letter
3. I'm sure that's a copy/paste issue but the class declaration doesn't use `()` in `class TestClass(){`.

With all that:

```
    class TestClass {
        var testString = "0"

        func testFunc() -> String {

            switch (testString) {
            case "0":
                testString = "5"
            case "5":
                testString = "8"
            case "8":
                testString = "12"
            case "12":
                testString = "17"
            case "17":
                testString = "25"
            default:
                break; // Do what you need in this case
            }

            return testString
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
    var test = TestClass()

    // ...

    @IBAction func test() {       
        print(test.testFunc())      
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and great tips!